# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0)

Tags: opencv, eclipse-cdt

I compiled and installed the OpenCV libraries as per the official tutorial as well as the following link [opencv-installation](http://www.ozbotz.org/opencv-installation/)

I used the sample code provided in the official tutorial using eclipse cdt

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1],1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
  {
     printf( "No image data \n" );
     return -1;
  }

   namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Display Image", image );

   waitKey(0);

   return 0;
}
```

Upon compiling i get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /home/hp/apps/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 261
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

what(): /home/hp/apps/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This code works for me. Try with another image...

Comment: its a standard code, i dont think its something wrong with the code rather something with my configuration

Comment: Have you tried another image?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem .You can add similar this code, maybe solve it. Because capture size cause this problem

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480); 

cap.read(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load a .PNG file? You need to load a specific plugin for it. If it is possible, use .bmp or .jpg files.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem - finally it turned out that it was problem with configuration. In the end, because of some weird errors (Eclipse CDT) I even deleted project and created new one with proper configuration settings.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error.

I change video Capture index

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Comment: and did that solve the problem for you?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).