# opencv error: assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in unknown function line 261

Tags: c++, opencv, width, line, assert

This is my code:

```
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    //create matrix to store image
    Mat image;

    //initialize capture    
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    cap.open(0);

    //create window to show image   
    namedWindow("window",1);

    while(1){   
        //copy webcam stream to image
        cap>>image;

        //print image to screen     
        imshow("window",image); //Error line

        //delay 33ms
        waitKey(33);
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
opencv error: assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in unknown function
file...\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp line 261
```

In window.cpp, line 261 is:

```
CV_Assert(size.width>0 && size.height>0);
```

---

I solved my problem. 
firstly, you can add this code

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
```

then add this code in while loop:

```
cap.read(image);
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17636587/1601291) appears similar to yours. It might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

`(size.width>0 && size.height>0)` means that there is an empty `Mat` over there. In this case, it must be that `image` is empty because the camera couldn't be opened. Check `VideoCapture::open` return value.

Comment: thank you but this code isn't my code and it work tutorial video.

Comment: The code is using a camera that may not be the same as in the tutorial.

Comment: Check `VideoCapture::open` return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
cap.open(0);
Sleep(1000);  // Wait for response of camera, don't forget to #include <windows.h>
```

chears